# "Conorm" image preprocessing

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing

For a personal project, I am trying to reproduce the MCDNN of the paper [Multi-column Deep Neural Networks for Image Classification](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.2745v1.pdf) by Ciresan, Meier, and Schmidhuber on CIFAR-10.

The different preprocessing they use are the same as for the Traffic Signs dataset, and are described in Figure 3. I have been able to reproduce the first 3 preprocessing options without issues, but I am at loss on what "Conorm" is, and I could not find out by searching on the internet (finding an aeronautic company and lots of images of Conor MacGregor instead).

Could anyone point me to a description of what Conorm means in this context or some useful reference?

Comment: see page 17 of the paper

Comment: @shimao Thanks! I have read the whole paper but I didn't focus too much on the traffic signs application, so I missed it. You can put this as an answer and I will accept it, if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @shimao, page 17 of the paper gives the answer. It references the paper [Traffic Sign Recognition with Multi-Scale Convolutional Networks](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/sermanet-ijcnn-11.pdf) by Sermanet and LeCun (end of Section II.B).